# Writefile causes crash, with access violation

Tags: c++, file-io, access-violation

So basically I wish to write a byte array to a file, however the program crashes. 
Unhandled exception at 0x7766DEE1 (KernelBase.dll) in append.exe: 0xC0000005: Access violation writing location 0x00000000.

```
BYTE *image ;
BYTE *bigMem;
#define REASONABLY_LARGE_BUFFER 16777216
file = CreateFile(fileName, GENERIC_READ | GENERIC_WRITE, 0, NULL, OPEN_EXISTING, FILE_ATTRIBUTE_NORMAL, NULL);

fileSize = GetFileSize(file, NULL);

bigMem = (BYTE *)HeapCreate(NULL, REASONABLY_LARGE_BUFFER, 0);
image = (BYTE *)HeapAlloc(bigMem, HEAP_ZERO_MEMORY, fileSize);
if (bigMem == NULL || image == NULL){
    printf("Allocation failed");
    return EXIT_FAILURE;
}
printf("We are writing to the file %p, with data location %p, and filesize %d\n", file, image, fileSize);
LPDWORD at = 0;
WriteFile(file, image, fileSize, at, NULL);
```

That print says:
We are writing to the file 00000038, with data location 02451590, and filesize 161169

Comment: Are you sure that 16MB is "reasonably large"? What if the OS doesn't want to give you that much heap memory and the allocation function returns `NULL`? You **never** check that, you should.

Comment: I just put the code in to check if either bigMem or image are null, and neither are.

Comment: If you're adding error checking, you should check that the file was actually opened too.

Comment: You should check for `bigMem == NULL` *before* passing it to `HeapAlloc`

Answer (score 18, accepted):

The argument passed to [`WriteFile`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa365747(v=vs.85).aspx) used to store the number of bytes written (`at`) can *only* be null if the argument for the overlapped structure is *not* null. I suggest changing `at` to be a `DWORD` and pass a pointer to it.

```
DWORD at;
WriteFile(file, image, fileSize, &at, NULL);
```

Comment: I cannot believe I missed that. Especially after looking at all the ones where they comment that it can't be null.

Comment: It happens, especially after you've looking at the same code for a while ;)

Comment: Thank you for the answer, but for the love of all that is holy, what were they thinking when they came up with that constraint?

Comment: @mercurytw perhaps: WriteFile gets a lot of use, so making its flow have an extra test and branch would be considered an unacceptable performance penalty.

Comment: This problem isn't present in Win8.1 by the way.

Comment: @FISOCPP Irrelevant, it could very well be present in 8.2 - follow the documentation and all will be good in the Universe.