# Embed .exe file into C++ program?

Tags: c++, windows, cygwin, exe, embed

I wrote a c++ program and I want to execute my second program inside it, which is a exe file. The problem is I want to share my program to others as one single file.

When I search on the internet, I found this solution.

> Just store the second .exe file as a binary resource inside the main
>   .exe using an .rc file at compile-time. At run-time, you can access it
>   using `FindResource()`, `LoadResource()`, and `LockResource()`, and then
>   write it out to a temp file on disk before passing it to `system()`.

But I don't understand how to "store the .exe file as a binary resource"

I am currently using `CreateProcess()` to start my second program which working greatly.
Can anyone write some example for me?

Comment: Storing it should not be different from storing any other binary resource. You will likely need to extract the file to some place on your hard drive to use it however.

Comment: Are you using Visual Studio? Do you have a resource script (`.rc` file) in your project? Do you understand how to use the resource editor? We need more info if we are to properly offer helpful solutions.

Comment: @drescherjm  Hello, thanks for your help. So I can just rename the .exe into .rc?..

Comment: ***So I can just rename the .exe into .rc?*** No but in your .rc file you can add the binary resource.

Comment: @AdrianMole Hi, I am using Cygwin since I use some Linux library in my program. I have no clue how to use the resource editor.

Comment: I can't help with cygwin.

Comment: Maybe you just want to use an installer program like nsis to package your files in a single executable. [https://nsis.sourceforge.io/Main_Page](https://nsis.sourceforge.io/Main_Page)

Comment: Is there a file or files with an `.rc` or `.rc2` extension anywhere in your project? (I also don't use Cygwin, but if there's a resource script, it can be edited to include a binary resource.)

Comment: @AdrianMole I use an .rc file to add an icon for my program. I need to compile the .rc 
 file to .res file first then I compile the .res with my main program.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In your project's resource script (the `.rc` file in which icons, dialogs, etc. are defined), you can add a binary resource with a line like the following:

```
IDB_EMBEDEXE    BINARY      "<path>\\EmbedProgram.exe"
```

Where the `IDB_EMBEDEXE` token/macro should be defined in a header file that is included by *both* that resource script *and* any C++ source(s) that use(s) it; this will be the `lpName` argument given to the `FindResource()` call, which you can form using `MAKEINTRESOURCE(IDB_EMBEDEXE)`. Specify `"BINARY"` (or `L"BINARY"` for Unicode builds) for the `lpType` argument.

Like this:

```cpp
#define IDB_EMBEDEXE 13232 // Or whatever suitable value you need
//...
// In the C++ code:
HRSRC hResource = FindResource(NULL, MAKEINTRESOURCE(IDB_EMBEDEXE), _TEXT("BINARY"));
HGLOBAL hGlobal = LoadResource(NULL, hResource);
size_t exeSiz = SizeofResource(NULL, hResource); // Size of the embedded data
void*  exeBuf = LockResource(hGlobal);           // usable pointer to that data

// You can now write the buffer to disk using "exeBuf" and "exeSiz"
```

The specified executable file will then be completely embedded (as a binary) resource in your *built* executable, and can be extracted, written to disk and executed as described in the article you quote.

Comment: Thank you very much for the answer, I am trying to understand it.

Comment: By changing `RT_RCDATA` to `"BINARY"`, `FindResource()` returns a handle so it works.

Comment: `MAKEINTRESOURCE(RT_RCDATA)` 
gives me error: cast from ‘LPSTR’ {aka ‘char*’} to ‘WORD’ {aka ‘short unsigned int’}

Comment: No I was wrong when I said I was wrong! `RT_RCDATA` is already defined as `MAKINTRESOURCE(10)`. I think I need some strong drink. Stick with using the `"BINARY"` name!!

Comment: Now things become complicated. After changing `RT_RCDATA` to `"BINARY"`, the program crash when `GlobalSize(hGlobal)`.

Comment: @JasonLam Yeah, of course it will (my fault, again). You can't use `GlobalSize()` here, but should use the `SizeofResource()` function (see edit). More strong drink!

Comment: @JasonLam Me wrong; you right (again)! Now I'm running out of strong drink. See edit.

Comment: Alright, everything is working like a charm. One more question, after I run the exe by `CreateProcess()`, how can I terminate it?

Comment: @JasonLam That would depend on the nature of the created program. It's also probably a new question in its own right. And I have no more strong drink left. ‎

Comment: Hi, thank you so much for your help. It runs smoothly on my Windows 10 PC. Recently, I tried the same program on a Windows 7 computer, it crashes when `WriteFile( hFile, exeBuf, exeSiz, NULL , NULL);` . How is this happening? I didn't encounter any problem on Windows 10. Thx

Comment: Have you made sure your Windows 7 PC has the latest updates and relevant run-time support packages. I don't know how CygWin uses these, but it probably targets the machine you're building on.

Comment: I fixed the problem by changing `NULL` to `&at`
[Reference](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17130532/writefile-causes-crash-with-access-violation). Thank you btw